# Joining two tables entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

i am trying to join two tables in entity framework using LINQ

Here are the models:

```
    public partial class PredbiljezbeEF
    {
        public int idPredbiljezba { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> datumPredbiljezba { get; set; }
        public string imePolaznik { get; set; }
        public string prezimePolaznik { get; set; }
        public string gradPolaznik { get; set; }
        public string adresaPolaznik { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> postanskiBrojPolaznik { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> statusPredbiljezba { get; set; }
        public int idSeminar { get; set; }

        public virtual SeminariEF SeminariEF { get; set; }
    }

        public partial class SeminariEF
    {

        public SeminariEF()
        {
            this.PredbiljezbeEFs = new HashSet<PredbiljezbeEF>();
        }

        public int idSeminar { get; set; }
        public string nazivSeminar { get; set; }
        public string opisSeminar { get; set; }
        public string datumSeminar { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> statusSeminar { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> brojPredbiljezbi { get; set; }
```

And here is the LINQ expression:

```
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            SeminariEntities db = new SeminariEntities();

            var predB = (from x in db.PredbiljezbeEFs
                         join y in db.SeminariEFs on x.idSeminar equals y.idSeminar
                         select new
                         {
                             id = x.idPredbiljezba,
                             ime = x.imePolaznik,
                             prez = x.prezimePolaznik,
                             datum = x.datumPredbiljezba,
                             grad = x.gradPolaznik,
                             adresa = x.adresaPolaznik,
                             post = x.postanskiBrojPolaznik,
                             status = x.statusPredbiljezba,
                             naziv = y.nazivSeminar,
                             datumS = y.datumSeminar

                         }).ToList();







            //var predB = (from x in db.PredbiljezbeEFs select x).ToList();

            gvPredbiljezbe.DataSource = predB.ToList();
            gvPredbiljezbe.DataBind();


        }
```

i am getting this error:

> DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`10[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=n...' does not contain a property with the name 'idPredbiljezba'.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Could you please share the GridView code?

Comment: Why join? Don't. You have a navigation property `PredbiljezbeEF.SeminariEF`.

Comment: I thought about it, but i am not so familiar with it. can you please write some example how to use it in this case.

Comment: Use navigation property

Comment: Well, `x.SeminariEF.nazivSeminar` etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception `message => something` (Data Grid may be?) is trying to access property with name  `[idPredbiljezba]` from your `gvPredbiljezbe` `dataSource` but the query final projection doesn't contain such property you project property `[idPredbiljezba]` as `[id]`

hope that helps